# omega 4 can't import external libraries Primary tabs

Tags: theming

I am learning to work with omega 4, but I have problem with importing external libraries. I am using PhpStorm and it shows that it cannot resolve import.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :development do

 # Sass, Compass and extensions.
 gem 'sass'                    # Sass.
 gem 'sass-globbing'           # Import Sass files based on globbing pattern.
 gem 'compass'                 # Framework built on Sass.
 gem 'compass-validator'       # So you can `compass validate`.
 gem 'compass-normalize'       # Compass version of normalize.css.
 gem 'compass-rgbapng'         # Turns rgba() into .png's for backwards  compatibility.
gem 'susy'                    # Susy grid framework.
gem 'singularitygs'           # Alternative to the Susy grid framework.
gem 'toolkit'                 # Compass utility from the fabulous Snugug.
gem 'breakpoint'              # Manages CSS media queries.
gem 'oily_png'                # Faster Compass sprite generation.
gem 'css_parser'              # Helps `compass stats` output statistics.

# Guard
gem 'guard'                   # Guard event handler.
gem 'guard-compass'           # Compile on sass/scss change.
gem 'guard-shell'             # Run shell commands.
gem 'guard-livereload'        # Browser reload.
gem 'yajl-ruby'               # Faster JSON with LiveReload in the browser.

# Dependency to prevent polling. Setup for multiple OS environments.
# Optionally remove the lines not specific to your OS.
# https://github.com/guard/guard#efficient-filesystem-handling
gem 'rb-inotify', '~> 0.9', :require => false      # Linux

end
```

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks for all answers.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to do.  Are you working locally or on a remote server?

Comment: I am working locally on Vagrant.

Comment: Have you installed rvm and run `bundle` from the theme directory?

Comment: I think, I am little but confused. I have installed rvm and bundle from theme directory on a virtual machine. I got there using vagrant ssh. But project I have opened in PhpStorm is a local project in my computer. I think, that's why it does not work, but I don't know how to open project from my virtual machine.